# Laravel: How to assign Organization to a user

Tags: laravel

I want to assign an organization to a user but what happens in my code is that when I create a new organization and it's ID is 1, it automatically assigns itself to user ID 1 also.

This is my AssignOrgToUser controller:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\organizations;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

class AssignOrgToUserController extends Controller
{
    public function assignOrg(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $users = User::find($id);
        if(is_null($users)){
            return response()->json(["message"=>"User not found!"], 404);
        }

        $rules=[  
            'organization'=>'required',
        ];
        
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors(),400);
        }

        $data = $request->validate([
            'organization'=>'required',
        ]);

        $orgs = organizations::where('id', '=', $request->organization)->first();
        if(is_null($orgs)){
            return response()->json(["message"=>"Organization not found!"], 404);
        }


        $orgs= $users->save();
        if($orgs){
            return ["result"=>"ORG Added"];
        }else{
            return ["result"=>"ORG not Added"];
        }

       

        // $users->save([$orgs]);
        // return response(['message'=>"Organization has beed added", $users]);
}
}
```

Organization Model:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class organizations extends Model
{
    public $table = "organizations";
    use HasFactory;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User'); #if column not found indicate the column name
    }

}
```

Any kind of help/suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this `$orgs= $users->save();` with the below code

For update use `associate` method do like this (in your Case)

```
  $orgs = Organisation::create(['someColumn' => $request->someColumn]);
  $orgs->users()->associate($users);
  $orgs->save();
```

for more https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Comment: pls  don't forget to upvote the answer also thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seams like the problem came from you Request URL, you have define you Controller to receive a paramater name `id` with that I can presume you have define the Route like this

```
Route::post("/assign_organization/{id}", [AssignOrgToUserController::class, "assignOrg"]);
```

If the request url contain a user ID which is `1` any time you'll try to create an organization it will be attached to a user which ID is 1. as you are retrieving the user based on the id get from the URL

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

If you want to assign an organization with a different User ID, you should pass that User ID in you request body. and that won't consider the URL Body

```
$user = User::find($request->get("user_id"));
```